# increasing a key, by knowing the value - python dictionary

Tags: python

I need to write a code, where for every time someone buys a product, the key in the demand dictionary increases by 1.
I couldn't figure out how to increase a key in a dictionary byknowing the value.

This is what I tried:

```
demand = {"bread":0,"butter":0,"cheese":0, "water":0,"ice cream":0}
# bread is the value and 0 is the key, which I want to increase every time

def bill(buy_lst):
    for item in buy_lst:
        demand[demand.get(item)] += 1
```

When I run it says:

```
demand[demand.get(item)] += 1
KeyError: 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: `bread` is the key, and `0` is the value. And you want to increase `0`, right?

Comment: You are not running your function `def bill()`.

Comment: There is another way to achieve your goal. See my code below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is how you are adding to the dictionary. Notice the following:

```py
demand = {"bread": 0, "butter": 0, "cheese": 0, "water": 0, "ice cream": 0}
buy_lst = ["bread", "butter", "bread"]

def bill(buy_lst):
    for item in buy_lst:
        print(demand.get(item))
        #demand[demand.get(item)] += 1

bill(buy_lst)
```

This outputs:

```
0
0
0
```

So in other words, in your:

```py
demand[demand.get(item)] += 1
```

You are doing:

```py
demand[0] += 1
```

Which will return the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/felipefaria/Desktop/test/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    bill(buy_lst)
  File "/Users/felipefaria/Desktop/test/main.py", line 8, in bill
    demand[demand.get(item)] += 1
KeyError: 0
```

Instead, you should be simply referring to the item itself within the brackets, like so:

```py
demand = {"bread": 0, "butter": 0, "cheese": 0, "water": 0, "ice cream": 0}
buy_lst = ["bread", "butter", "bread"]

def bill(buy_lst):
    for item in buy_lst:
        demand[item] += 1

bill(buy_lst)
print(demand)
```

Which will output:

```
{'bread': 2, 'butter': 1, 'cheese': 0, 'water': 0, 'ice cream': 0}
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete and detailed anwer :) I have a test tommorow I you really helped me!!

Comment: I highly recommend playing around with dictionaries then, and reading up on their official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). I think a lot of things will click once you take a look at it! :)

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out!

Comment: Also, make sure to press the checkmark next to whichever answer you found most useful so your question is marked as "answered" to the rest of the community!

Answer (score 0):

You seems to misunderstand `key` and `value`, in your case the string are the `keys` and their quantity is the `value`

```
demand = {"bread": 0, "butter": 0, "cheese": 0, "water": 0, "ice cream": 0}
```

So what you want is increase value given a key

```
buy_lst[item] += 1
```

---

To use it, you need something that ask the user one product like

```
def bill(buy_lst):
    item = None
    while not item:
        item = input("Please select in " + str(list(buy_lst.keys())))
        item = item if item in buy_lst else None
    buy_lst[item] += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demand = {"bread": 0, "butter": 0, "cheese": 0, "water": 0, "ice cream": 0}
    bill(demand)
    print(demand)
```

Comment: @princess_python You're welcome ;) Choose one of the answers and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to mean was 'increasing value of a key that I know'. Because only values are ints so only they can be incremented. So incrementing value would be:

```py
demand = {"bread":0,"butter":0,"cheese":0, "water":0,"ice cream":0}

def bill(buy_lst):
    for item in buy_lst:
        demand[item] += 1
```

For clarifying, dictionary item's first part is `key` and second part is `value`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing key and value. In `demand`, the keys are the items and the values are the counts.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

demand = {"bread":0, "butter":0, "cheese":0, "water":0, "ice cream":0}
def bill(buy_list):
    for item in buy_list:
        demand[item] += 1

buy_list = ["bread", "water"]

print("Before billing:")
print(demand)

bill(buy_list)

print("After billing")
print(demand)
```

This prints:

```
Before billing:
{'bread': 0, 'butter': 0, 'cheese': 0, 'water': 0, 'ice cream': 0}
After billing
{'bread': 1, 'butter': 0, 'cheese': 0, 'water': 1, 'ice cream': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is really simple. You just have to add the operator `*` in front of the function parameter `buy_lst`, so you will have `*buylst`. See the below code:

```
demand = {"bread":0,"butter":0,"cheese":0, "water":0,"ice cream":0}
# bread is the value and 0 is the key, which I want to increase every time

def bill(*buy_lst):  # see this line
    for item in buy_lst:
        demand[item] += 1  # see this line

bill("bread", "cheese") # The client buys the products `bread` and `cheese`
print(demand)
bill("bread", "cheese", "water", "butter")
print(demand)
```

> **Output**

```
{'bread': 1, 'butter': 0, 'cheese': 1, 'water': 0, 'ice cream': 0}
{'bread': 2, 'butter': 1, 'cheese': 2, 'water': 1, 'ice cream': 0}
```

Comment: the operator * means I can summon the procedure with multipole operators?